# MFPPush registerDevice with userId in Hybrid (Cordova)

Tags: push-notification, ibm-cloud, ibm-mobile-services

Below is mentioned in Bluemix site but get undefined function while calling.

```
MFPPush.initialize("appGUID of push", "clientSecret of push");
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran the [Bluemix Cordova hellopush sample](https://github.com/ibm-bluemix-mobile-services/bms-samples-cordova-hellopush) which should help you out. Make sure you follow the directions in the README, and make sure to change the route and guid in your **index.js** (it should look something like this):

```
route: "http://imfpush.ng.bluemix.net",
guid: "djkslk3j2-4974-4324-8e82-421c02ce847c",
```

You will be able to find the route and guid in your Push Notifications service credentials.

---

After running it by following the directions (and ensuring that you have GCM / APNS set up correctly for whatever platform you are using), you should be greeted with this screen after clicking register:

[image]

Comment: Let me know if this solves your problem, or if you need any more help.